# Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 | react-native-vector-icons

Tags: android, react-native, android-appcompat, react-native-vector-icons

I was trying to compile [location-saver](https://github.com/vaskort/location-saver) that has a dependency [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/) that I was not able to build.

The build was failing after a lot of attempts. Here is the log:

```
react-native run-android
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons'.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:_debugCompile'.
      > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1.
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/Users/gureks/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.pom
            file:/Users/gureks/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.jar
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.pom
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.jar
            file:/Users/gureks/Desktop/Github/reacting/location-saver/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.pom
            file:/Users/gureks/Desktop/Github/reacting/location-saver/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.jar
            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.pom
            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.jar
            file:/Users/gureks/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.pom
            file:/Users/gureks/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.jar
            file:/Users/gureks/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.pom
            file:/Users/gureks/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.jar
        Required by:
            LocationSaver:react-native-vector-icons:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 16.274 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

I even changed the Support Library versions in the build.grade of the react-native-vector node_module.

Need help for a project, new to react-native.

Comment: can you add  your gradle file

Comment: You can find it here - https://github.com/vaskort/location-saver/blob/master/android/build.gradle